# Work with escaping closure value

Tags: swift

Have this to fill my full fullJsonData array
and i want to work with value after closure.

```
func getNewsAsDic(completionHandler: @escaping ([fullJsonData]) -> [fullJsonData]) {

    let session = URLSession.shared
    let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: requestNewsForToday()) { data, _, error in
        if error == nil {
            if let dic = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary {
                var dataArray = [fullJsonData]()

                let jdata = dic?["articles"] as! [[String:Any]]

                for item in jdata {

                    let data = fullJsonData(author: item["author"] as? String,
                                            description: item["description"] as? String,
                                            publishedAt: item["publishedAt"] as? String,
                                            title: item["title"] as? String,
                                            url: item["url"] as! String,
                                            imageURL: item["urlToImage"] as? String)

                    print(item["author"] as! String)
                    print(item["description"] as! String)
                    print(item["title"] as! String)
                    print(item["urlToImage"] as! String)
                    print(item["url"] as! String)
                    print(item["urlToImage"] as! String)
                    print(item["publishedAt"] as! String)

                    dataArray.append(data)
                }
                completionHandler(dataArray)
                print(jdata.count)
            }
        } else {
            return
        }
    }
    dataTask.resume()
}
```

So problem is:
1)The xcode error, what `Result of call is unused, but produces '[fullJsonData]'`
2)Then I am trying to use it in project like this:

```
var dataArray = [fullJsonData]()
        dataArray = NetworkManager.shared.getNewsAsDic(completionHandler: { dict in
            return dict
        })
```

Had an error too: `Cannot assign value of type '()' to type '[fullJsonData]'`

So is this real to take and use values from closure?

Answer (score 0):

You should change the signature of your completion handler from:

```
func getNewsAsDic(completionHandler: @escaping ([fullJsonData]) -> [fullJsonData]) {
```

to:

```
func getNewsAsDic(completionHandler: @escaping ([fullJsonData]) -> Void) {
```

And then change your call to:

```
NetworkManager.shared.getNewsAsDic(completionHandler: { myArray in
    // Do whatever you want with myArray here
})
```

Also, you should rename `getNewsAsDic` because you're really returning an array.

Comment: But I want to do somthing with myArr value outside closure. Like take count and implement in other functions

Comment: The call to `session.dataTask` is asynchronous (or non-blocking) because even though it might take 20 seconds to get a reply from the server, code execution does not stop. That's why you have a `completion` callback - that is where you put the code that you want to execute when a server response is received.

Answer (score 0):

it seems you have to use

`var dataArray: [fullJsonData] = []` instead of your code.